# Getting an error message trying to get a table (tabular)

Tags: tables

I am getting an error message while trying to get this table:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\textwidth= 5.00in
\textheight= 7.4in
\topmargin = 30pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=55pt
\headsep=17pt
\parskip=.5pt
\parindent=12pt
\font\smallit=cmti10
\font\smalltt=cmtt10
\font\smallrm=cmr9

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath,epsfig,amsthm,enumerate} 

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}
{-30pt \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}

\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}

\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname. }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Examples for all values of the parameters are given below. 

\begin{tabular*}{}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
$x_0 = x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 \leq \dots \leq x_n$ & $A(x) = 4$ & $B=1$\\
$x_0 = x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_5 \leq \dots \leq x_n$ & $A(x) = 4$ & $B=2$\\
$x_0 = x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_6 \leq \dots \leq x_n$ & $A(x) = 4$ & $B=3$\\
$x_0 = x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_7 \leq \dots \leq x_n$ & $A(x) = 4$ & $B=4, \text{ etc.}$
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

What can be fixed?

Comment: From the first point of view, I think you missed the mandatory argument for width of the tabular* environment, which is empty. Try to fill in it.

Answer (score 3):

The error message highlights where the error is

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.37 \begin{tabular*}{}
                       {@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
?
```

The argument has to be a width, such as `\textwidth` not empty.

Unrelated but do not use `epsfig` in any document written since 1993, and never use `\font` in latex.

Comment: Or use `\font` and never use LaTeX :).

Comment: @wipet I assume a command defined with `\font` wouldn't cooperate with optex's font handling either?

Comment: The section 2.12 "Using \font primitive directly" of OpTeX documentation describes, how to use `\font` with OpTeX's font selection system.

Comment: @wipet or more particularly `The \setfontsize macro` oh so you can recover a managed font declaration from the primitive font, quite nice, although telling users not to use `\font` in the first place is even nicer:-)

Comment: The error message says:  Overfull \hbox (12.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines ...   I edited it and put \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}, but then the columns are too far from each other. How can I keep the columns the same size as they were before?

Comment: @Vika that is not an error, that is a warning, you have started a paragraph with a 12pt indentation then had a tabular textwidth wide, so it is 12pt too wide, use `begin{center}..\end{center}` or similar so it is  not indented. If you do not want to stretch out the columns do not use `tabular*`  that is it's entire function!!!  Just use `\begin{tabular}{lll}`